# Trigger PowerShell from TeamCity to create excel

Tags: excel, powershell, teamcity

I am using TeamCity to trigger a PowerShell script located on the TeamCity build agent. The script gets triggered but the excel creation code doesn't work. I have tried using x86 vs 64 bit PowerShell ISE with x86 vs 64 bit MS Office but getting same error. Any idea if excel can be created/controlled using TeamCity? Is it even possible?

Note:
If I run the PowerShell code from the build agent directly, without using TeamCity, things works as expected.

Code:

```
$excel = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$excel.visible = $false
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Add()
$wksht= $workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
```

Error:

```
The remote procedure call failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BE)
At D:\BuildAgent\work\5e0b907c7938386b\Src\CreateExcel\CreateExcel_Main.psm1:148 char:5
+     $workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Add()
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
 
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At D:\BuildAgent\work\5e0b907c7938386b\Src\CreateExcel\CreateExcel_Main.psm1:149 char:5
+     $wksht= $workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with TeamCity, but the following _may_ apply: Running Office applications via Windows services is not officially supported - see [this Microsoft support article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office). The workaround in [this superuser.com answer](https://superuser.com/a/655458/139307) _may_ be effective. Better to look for alternatives such as the [DocumentFormat.OpenXml nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/), although that doesn't cover Outlook.

Comment: Thanks, I did tried that solution yesterday with no luck.